# PhysicsJS - Creating rope & attach something at the end of it

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, physicsjs

**Question #1:**
I'm new to PhysicsJS, and i tried to create a rope with idea of "[Basket of verlet constraints](http://wellcaffeinated.net/PhysicsJS/#demo-5)"
something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REGCU/17/)
as you see, this rope is not acting natural! (friction, rope wight, stability time & ...) 
and by increasing the length of rope, it got worse!
first i think, by increasing the mass of ropes particles, it will slow down faster but ...

```
var basket = [];
var fpos = window.innerWidth / 2;
var epos = window.innerHeight / 2;
for ( var i = fpos; i < fpos + epos; i += 5 ){

    l = basket.push(
        Physics.body('circle', {
            x: i
            ,y: 50 - (i-fpos)
            ,radius: 1
            ,restitution: 0
            ,mass: 1000
            ,conf: 1
            ,hidden: true
        })
    );

    rigidConstraints.distanceConstraint( basket[ l - 1 ], basket[ l - 2 ], 2 );
}
```

**Question #2:**
after fixing that, how can i crate this:
(attaching a rectangular box at the end of rope)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a box and attach it to the end of the rope:

```
var box = Physics.body('rectangle', {
    x: i
    ,y: 50 - (i-fpos)
    ,width: 60
    ,height: 60
    ,styles: { fillStyle: '#fff' }
});

rigidConstraints.distanceConstraint( basket[ l - 1 ], box, 2 );

world.add(box);
```

Which results in something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/REGCU/14/
But unfortunately at this time there isn't yet a way to handle adding constraints to the edge of the box as you've drawn.

It's an outstanding issue: https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/issues/5